# Выбрать несколько элементов для querySelector в JS

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Есть код, по клику на элемент .button, показывается или скрывается тултип (tooltip.show : tooltip.hide).

1. Как сделать так, чтобы было два селектора, допустим button_1 и button_2. Я думал это должно выглядеть как ('.button_1', '.button_2'), но кажется не работает
2. Как здесь же выполнить tooltip.hide при клике по области за .button

   ```
   <script>
       (function Example () {
           var flag = false;

           document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
               flag = !flag;

               (flag ? tooltip.show : tooltip.hide)(e.target);
           });
       }());
   </script>
   ```

Comment: функции `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` принимают в качестве параметра **одну** строку с **css** селектором. Поэтому чтобы было несколько селекторов, надо вводить так, как это было бы в css: селекторы должны быть разделены запятой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выбрать несколько элементов для querySelector в JS

Вот так например:

```js
(function Example() {
  var flag = false;

  var btns = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=button_]')
  btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      flag = !flag;

      (flag ? tooltip.show : tooltip.hide)(e.target);
    });
  })
}());
```

```html
<button class="button_1"> Clck 1</button>
<button class="button_2"> Clck 2</button>
```